# How do I interpret this: <-chan int(c)?

Tags: go

This is from: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions

`<-chan int(c)    // same as <-(chan int(c))`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the following expressions,  `<-` is the [receive operator](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Receive_operator) and `chan int` is a type.

```
<-chan int(c)  
<-(chan int(c))
```

The expressions convert `c` to `chan int` and receive on the result of the conversion.

In next expression, `<-` is part of the type.  The `<-` indicates that the channel is receive-only.

```
(<-chan int)(c)
```

The expression converts `c` to a receive only channel of `int`.